# Eager loading return type inside method

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two classes Product and Subscriptions both have relationship through ProjectId.

```
public class Project
{

    [MaxLength(40)]
    [Required()]
    [Key()]
    public String ProjectId { get; set; }


    [MaxLength(128)]
    [Required()]
    public String Name { get; set; }

   public virtual ICollection<Subscriptions> Subscriptions { get; set; }

}

public class Subscriptions
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(40)]
    public string ProjectId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ProjectId")]
    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }

}
```

Now I have a below method which needs to return combine values from both the classes. But I want to keep return type as Project as I want to avoid ViewModel. But it is not including values from Child table i.e. Subscriptions while returning values

```
public IQueryable<Project> GetProjects()
{
    return DataContext.Project.Include("Subscriptions").AsQueryable();        
}
```

Comment: _"it is not including values from Child table"_ - then there's no data.

Comment: You mean it is returning Projects but the Subscription property of project is empty? You are lazy loading and eager loading the Subscription entities so it should be loading them if the relationship exists.

Comment: Try removing virtual before Subscribtions - this will enable eager loading for it.

Comment: no i mean how can i get Subscription table values through my method ? Being the Project entity as return type

Comment: Try var Projects = DataContext.Project.Include(p => p.Subscriptions).ToList(); Always try to use object instead of string names. If this returns no data i think there may be a relation issue.

Comment: You can't return a subscription entity from your method being as it expects a project type. You can only return a project with a linked subscription entity, unless you change the method signature.